# installation of paraview 5.4.1 version in ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: upgrade

can somebody help me with commands (in terminal) that need to install parview-5.4.1.Currently,I am using paraview-5.0.1 which is installed as default like other software packages in ubuntu-16.04 lts.

Comment: Did you find any of what was posted useful?
It is good for the community to provide feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The supported version of paraview for Ubuntu 16.04 is **5.0.1**. Of course you can try to install a different version manually, but you may encounter errors and it may be difficult or even impossible to install the package due to unmet dependencies.

To install a different version of `paraview` manually, follow these steps:

1. deinstall the current installed version:

   ```
   sudo apt remove paraview
   ```
2. download the `.deb` package you want to install
3. to install it, click the `.deb` file or run

   ```
   sudo apt install /path/to/package.deb
   ```

If you need to install a `tar.gz` file, follow these instructions: [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030/507051)

However, I recommend to stick to the supported version for your current Ubuntu release, you're on the safe side this way. If you want to use more up-to-date software you should consider updating to the current release 17.04 – it has `paraview` v5.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

I simply downloaded `ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit.tar.gz`, uncompressed it, and executed `ParaView-5.4.1-Qt5-OpenGL2-MPI-Linux-64bit/bin/paraview`.

I did not bother yet modifying my `PATH`.

I expected this method to have some issues, but I still found none.